# Creating appropriate array from request values in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how to properly structure request data into an array in my controller. I have 3 values coming from my http request and I'm trying to get two of them into a specific array structure. My request values are dumping so they are definitely there.

Here's my controller where I"m putting them into an array:

```
 $subItems = array("title" => $request->itemTitle, "description" => $request->itemDesc);
```

But it's failing because the function I'm calling with the array `$subItems` is expecting an array structure where it can get the paramaters by the index of title and description like this:

```
 [ $subtask['title'], $subtask['description']]
```

How do I need to change my controller/array code to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use like this
$subItems['title'] = $request->itemTitle ;
After you cant get values using its key.

In your question you add values to $subItems but you getting values from $subtask . Please check that one also.

Comment: This is weird. What does var_dump($subItems) give you inside the function you are calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below

```
$subItems = [];
$subItems['title'] = $request->itemTitle;
$subItems['description'] = $request->itemDesc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
$subItems['title'] = $request->itemTitle;
```

After you cant get values using its key. 
In your question you add values to **$subItems** but you getting values from **$subtask** Please check that one also.